# The remote host closed the connection - asp.net MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

and I keep getting this error message when my website builds a PDF and opens the dialog to allow the user to Save it or Open it.

This is the full error in Elmah:

```
The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x800704CD
```

Now, I'm fairly sure the user never sees this error, but my logs are full of them and I just want rid of it!

Clicking on a link on my page links to a controller action that builds the pdf.  Here is the last part of the code for that:

```
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=filename.pdf");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        stream.Close();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

        Return View();
```

I think it's the `Response.End()` that is throwing the error because the action is trying to proceed after the response has ended.  Does that sound correct?  If so, is there anything I can do to prevent it?

Even though the user doesn't see the error, I see it and it must be solved!

Thanks - let me know if you need more info

Comment: Yes, you can't `Return View()` after the response has ended, because then it's trying to send more HTML in a response that's already been sent back to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the `FileResult` type to return the file content.  Here's a link to the MSDN documentation:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult(v=vs.98).aspx

To answer your question, Response.End causes the thread to immediately abort and any code that tries to run after that will throw an exception on the server side.  Since the response has already been delivered to the client, it would only appear in logs.

Manipulation of the raw Response object is generally frowned upon in MVC, since that bypasses the magical underpinnings of the framework.

Populating a `FileResult` will allow you to perform your work, provide the file content as a stream and name the downloaded file.  Once you've populated the desired properties, just return the `FileResult` instead of returning `View()`.